# jQuery element stored with `click` event not working as required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**One of my APP dev requires**

I clone a `link` 3 times and stored in to an object. after i stored to object i have added some click event to stored object's `link` element.

I have a navigation link, when user click on the navi number, i am appending the stored element to container.

All it works. the issue is:

the `click` event of the `link` only works on page load. it's  not working after shuffling the other stored object to container.

how to fix this. the event all are goes away. `click` event not working further.

here is my js:

```
var listLength = $('li').length;
var origional = $('.content');
var catcheEl = {};

    for(i=1;i<= listLength;i++){
        catcheEl['content'+i] = origional.clone();
        var link = $(catcheEl['content'+i]).find('a').addClass('link'+i);
        addEvent(link);
    }

function addEvent (link) {
    var x = 0;
    link.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        console.log(x);
        $(this).addClass('p'+x); //only adds on page load.
    });
}

$('li').click(function(){
    var num = $(this).find('button').prop('class');
    $('#newContainer').html(catcheEl['content'+num]); //not working once other elements loaded.
});

$('.content').hide();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9zpktajf/1/)

What i require is :

1. I should shuffle the `link` element clicking the navi button
2. the class name of `element` should continue
3. the added event should be continue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: that for loop which runs on listlength and call addevent is called on onload??

Comment: I think you meant "cacheEl" when you wrote "catcheEl" above... I'd consider renaming it for clarity.

Comment: already there.. click on Live demo. or here http://jsfiddle.net/9zpktajf/1/

Comment: use event delegation and get rid of `addEvent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT NEW ANSWER**
I don't like it so much since it relies on the class value(you should do some some security check, but...basically I have edited the way you define `x`, so I have retrieved all the classes of a, the splitted them, checked the lenght of the array.
Then if it is `1` (only `link` class) or `0` (don't know, just in case) or is not an array then set `0` otherwise retrieve the last array element and remove all the non numeric digit(hopefully, don't know about null byte or similar funny guys).

```
var listLength = $('li').length,
    origional = $('.content'),
    catcheEl = {};

function addEvent(link) {
    //Define the x variable
    var v=link.attr('class').split(/\s+/),
        l=v.length,
        x= (v.constructor === Array && (l==1 || l===0))? 0:parseInt(v[l-1].replace(/\D/g,''));

    link.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $(this).addClass('p' + x);
    });
}

for (i = 1; i <= listLength; i++) {
    catcheEl['content' + i] = origional.clone();
    var link = $(catcheEl['content' + i]).find('a').addClass('link' + i);
    addEvent(link);
}

$('li').click(function () {
    var num = $(this).find('button').prop('class');
    $('#newContainer').html(catcheEl['content' + num]);
    addEvent($(catcheEl['content' + num]).find('a')); //Re-bind the event
});

$('.content').hide();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9zpktajf/7/)

Comment: Actually i tried this already. i am getting event triggered 2 tiems instead single.

Comment: @3gwebtrain I'm ignorant, but if you remove an element from the document, does the binded function stay  attached to it?

Comment: I am not sure. that's what i posted this question. i am trying to find a work-around too..